# How do I get the user role using Zend framework2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, rbac

I am using Zend Framework 2 and having trouble getting the user role.  I am using zfc user and Zfc Rbac.  The roles currently work however I would like to get the values to use in an if statement (in the controller).  What is the function to call these?  I have the developer tool turned on so I can see the role assigned but can't figure out out to call it.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, would you create a select (form element) with list of roles?! Is a correct example?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was used the below code and was able to get the role of the logged in user.

```
 $viewmodel = new ViewModel();
 $authorize = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserRbac\Identity\IdentityRoleProvider');
 $roles = $authorize->getIdentityRoles();
 echo $roles[0];
    $viewmodel->setVariable("roles", $roles);
return $viewmodel;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup you identify correctly in ZfcRbac, then you can use the authorization service (ZfcRbac\Service\AuthorizationService) to get the identity and its roles.

```
$authorizationService->getIdentity()->getRoles();
```

Comment: Do I need to do something in the module.php?  I can see the role in the developer tool but get the below error when I try the above code (construct() **must be an instance of ...\ZfcRbac\Service\Rbac).**  In the Identity Provider I use  'UserRbac\Identity\IdentityProvider'      I see the role used in the database in the zend developer tool.